# How to go next page after login successfully using angularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I have restful api for **login** which has written in "**Laravel PHP**". I have to use that restfull api with angularjs. And after getting successfully login response,  new page should open,  for doing this I am using "**ngRoute**", but I am not able to do it properly.

Can anybody tell how can I do this.

Here is my code:

```
var QAApp = angular.module('QAApp', ['ngRoute', 'emoji', 'ngSanitize']);

//Route Provider from one page to another page

  QAApp.config(function($routeProvider ,  $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
          when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
          }).
          when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'QA.html',
            controller: 'askbyctrl'
          }).
            otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
          });
      });
```

**Login Controller:**

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $http, $location){

  // create a blank object to hold our form information
  // $scope will allow this to pass between controller and view

   $scope.formData = {};
  //Login Function
     $scope.login = function() {
     var request = $http({
                      method: 'POST', 
                      url: server + 'api/login',
                      data : $.param($scope.formData),
                      headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
                   });

    request.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert(data.error+' '+data.description);
        /*console.log(data);*/
        $scope.response = data;
        });

    };
```

Please tell me how I can do this.

Comment: Use `$location.path('/login')` in your success callback.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to add $window.location.href = 'your.address.com'; in your .success ?

```
request.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert(data.error+' '+data.description);
        /*console.log(data);*/
        $scope.response = data;
        $window.location.href = 'your.address.com';
        });
```